# How to filter list of objects in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

```
       "1": {
            "name": "Joe",          
            "frontend": "0",         
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Orange",
            "frontend": "1",
        },
```

I am using if else checking if front-end is "1" need show name("Orange) and need know is selected object "2"

or

I am using if else checking if front-end is "0" need show name("Joe) and need know is selected object "1"

Comment: You need to serialize  `JSON` inside model classes.

Comment: It's quite unclear to me, what you are asking. Could you maybe describe an example user doing something in your app and then post the code you have so far and where you are stuck?